# Detect time button is pushed

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to write a little code that detects how long a button connected to my Raspberry Pi is pushed down, not just if it's pushed. Is there an easy way to do this with Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to detect whenever the state of the button is toggled. When toggled if it's pushed down you will need to store the current time with `pressedTime = time.time()`. When released, to get how long the button have been pushed down, you just do : `howLong = time.time() - pressedTime`